# When does an undefined variable throw an Uncaught TypeError instead of just having a value of 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, undefined, undefined-behavior

Basically in the code I am editing, there's a function that receives an object argument that has 2 possible key/value pairs, but only either gets used depending on some condition:

This is the function that destructures the `foobar` into the individual keys:

```
function someFunction({ foo, bar }) {
  console.log(foo); // can be either { foo: "123"} or undefined
  console.log(bar); // can be either { bar: "321"} or undefined
}
```

This is where we pass the `foobar` argument to `someFunction()`:

```
function anotherFunction(foobar) {
  console.log(foobar); // can be either { foo: "123"} or { bar: "321"}
  someFunction(foobar);
}
```

This is where the `foobar` argument originates and its value depends on some condition:

```
if(someConditionIsMet) {
  anotherFunction({ foo: "123"});
} else {
  anotherFunction({ bar: "321"});
}
```

But sometimes, if I have an undefined variable somewhere, I will get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` and the program won't run at all.

E.g. when I call `someFunction(foobar)`, I was expecting to get an Uncaught TypeError because definitely one of the variables will be `undefined`. However, here the function still runs.

Why is this so?

Comment: "*But sometimes, if I have an undefined variable somewhere*" - please post the code that produces this error, not the code that is working

Comment: @Bergi I guess it's a valid question also when something works and you're not sure why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined variables are exactly that: variables, *names*, that you have used in your code, but which the runtime has no idea what it's supposed to refer to, because you have never *introduced* that variable name.

Here you are clearly introducing `foo` and `bar` as *function parameters*. It's clear to the runtime where those variables come from, what their scope is etc. Its simply that they haven't been assigned a value/they hold the value `undefined`. *Undefined variables* are variables which you suddenly refer to without having declared them anywhere with `var`, `let`, `const`, or as function parameters. E.g.:

```js
console.log(foo);
```

I have never defined what `foo` is, where it comes from or what its value is supposed to be, so this is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Many programming languages are designed on the principle that if a piece of code is unlikely to behave as intended, squawking as soon as possible is preferable to simply letting the code behave in the unintended fashion.  While many aspects of JavaScript are unhelpful in this regard, the `"use strict"` dialect attempts to offer assistance in some cases where it is able to do so.

The situation described here is a particularly important one from that regard because in the non-`"use strict"` dialect, an attempt to use a variable in a function where it is not defined has a valid specified meaning (create the variable in an outer context) which is sometimes relied upon.  Although there are some situations where `"use strict"` will cause code with one valid meaning to instead have a different valid meaning, most of them wouldn't arise terribly often.  If the meaning of code which attempts to use a variable that isn't defined in a function were changed to create the variable within that function, code which relies upon the old behavior would cease to work without any diagnostic indicating why.